How do I sum the 7 cells beside a correct match using Vlookup?
I have two Google Sheets. One is a list of dates in sequence in Column A (9/1/24; 9/2/24; etc..) and in Column B are number values associated with some of the dates.
Sheet 1:
9/1/2024    
9/2/2024    
9/3/2024    
9/4/2024    
9/5/2024    
9/6/2024    
9/7/2024    
9/8/2024    
9/9/2024    $750
9/10/2024   
9/11/2024   $500
9/12/2024   
9/13/2024   
9/14/2024   
9/15/2024   $400

The other sheet is a list of dates of Sundays in Column A (9/1/24; 9/8/24; 9/15/24; etc...) and in Column B, I would like to write a formula that would search the first sheet for the date in the second sheet, then return the sum of the number values that are in its Column B associated with that week. I'm having trouble figuring out how to have the formula sum the 7 values beside the date if found.
Sheet 2:
Income
9/01/24 
9/08/24 
9/15/24 
9/22/24 
9/29/24 
10/06/24    
10/13/24    
10/20/24

I am making a budgeting tool.
I have tried searching Google for the answers but to no avail. I'm familiar with VLookup and XLookup and SumIF, so I'm sure there's a simple way that you guys will be able to point out.
Thanks!

Utilize WEEKNUM() function. Filter data based on week number then sum up. Try-
=MAP(D1:D8,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(Sheet1!B1:B,INDEX(WEEKNUM(Sheet1!A1:A))=WEEKNUM(x))),0)))

I have used MAP() function to make the formula dynamic spill so that you do not need to drag down the formula manually to each cell.


Woah @harun24hr, you nailed it. I'll have to pull your formula apart to understand how those functions are playing into each other, but thanks!

@JoeSmith To understand the formula first use this simpler version =SUM(FILTER($B$1:$B,INDEX(WEEKNUM($A$1:$A))=WEEKNUM(D1))). Then use MAP() to make it dynamic spill formula. It the formula works then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark the answer).
